# Reset angle of text in skewed div using CSS

Tags: css

I have made a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/89x4d/

I'm trying to maintain the skewed div but keep the p text straight.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `20deg` instead of `0deg` on P to compensate for the DIV transform (since the result is the composition of transforms.)

Answer (score 5):

In order to cancel the effect of the skew, you have to give positive value of transformation.

```
p {
   -webkit-transform: skew(20deg) !important;
   -moz-transform: skew(20deg) !important;
   -o-transform: skew(20deg) !important;
   transform: skew(20deg) !important;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/89x4d/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height:50px;
        background: red;
-webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
-moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
-o-transform: skew(-20deg);
    transform: skew(-20deg);
    margin: 20px;
    
    padding:0 25px;
}
p {
   -webkit-transform: skew(20deg) !important;
-moz-transform: skew(20deg) !important;
-o-transform: skew(20deg) !important;
    transform: skew(20deg) !important; 
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>hey i'm straight, ok?</p>
</div>
```

hey i'm straight, ok?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can get it to skew back, seems to distort the font too much.

skew(20) is the closest i could get, but instead you could setup 2 divs, 1 for a skew box and another to then move over it.

http://jsfiddle.net/gP9ne/3/

Setup a fiddle there for you to see

Martyn

edit: actually doesnt look any different :p i think its just the black on red with the font doesnt like my screen :p

always over thinking!

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, reversing the `skew` of the `<p>` can lead to some undesirable results.

It's also not super reusable in that for every new `skew` angle you would need a corresponding CSS selector/declaration to reverse the internal content.

As an alternative, use the `:before` selector to add the skewed element behind the text.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <p>hey i'm straight, ok?</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height:50px;
  margin: 20px;
  position:relative;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display:block;
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:-1;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

And a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/zyq6nwyc/).