# how to prevent transformation of text inherited from a skewed parent

Tags: html, css, transformation

Hie,i am trying to prevent the text inside a link from skewing together with the parent. here is how it looks

```css
.one {
 width:300px;
 height:250px;
 list-style:none;
 color:#FFF;
}
.one li {
 
 width: 115px;
   height: 100px;
  
  text-align:center;
 
   
 
   display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform: translate(0px, -1px) skew(0deg, -5deg);
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1px) skew(0deg, -5deg);
-o-transform: translate(0px, -1px) skew(0deg, -5deg);
-ms-transform: translate(0px, -1px) skew(0deg, -5deg);
transform: translate(0px, -1px) skew(0deg, -5deg);
 background-color:rgba(239,82,85,1.00);
}
.one li a {


-moz-transform: translate(0px, 1px) skew(0deg, 5deg);
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 1px) skew(0deg, 5deg);
-o-transform: translate(0px, 1px) skew(0deg, 5deg);
-ms-transform: translate(0px, 1px) skew(0deg, 5deg);
transform: translate(0px, 1px) skew(0deg, 5deg);
  
 
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
<ul>



<li>

<a href="#">this is the test</a>


</li>
<li>

<a href="#">this is the test</a>


</li>


</ul>

</div>
```

I have read these articles from here with similar problem but seems mine is a  bit different.    [Slant the top of a div using css without skewing text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591584/slant-the-top-of-a-div-using-css-without-skewing-text) and     [Reset angle of text in skewed div using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271438/reset-angle-of-text-in-skewed-div-using-css). Please help me with the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS transforms don't work on inline elements in Webkit browsers (Safari and Chrome). Only "block" and "inline-block" elements can be transformed. (It's sort of like a bug, see https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58965 )

As a workaround, you can add this:

```
.one li a { display:inline-block; }
```

Another option would be to add a wrapper div around the anchor element, and apply the transform on that.

Comment: Perfect @Leon, please explain what this changes !

Comment: Thanks, now makes perfect sence