# RegEx wrap every word in a span tag

Tags: php, html

As the title suggests im trying to wrap every word in a `<span>` tag server-side. But iam missing the right RegEx.

**My current PHP Code looks like this.**

```
 function exampleFunction($text)
{

  $re1 = '/(<.*>)(.*)(<\/.*>)/';
  $str = $text;
  preg_match_all($re1, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

  $result = NULL;
  foreach($matches as $key => $value) {
    $words = $value[2];
    $start_tag = $value[1];
    $end_tag = $value[3];

    $re2 = '/(\w+|.)/';
    preg_match_all($re2, $words, $word_matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

    $paragraph = $start_tag;

    foreach($word_matches as $key => $value) {
      if($value[0] != " ") {
        $paragraph .= '<span>'.$value[0].'</span>';
      } else {
        $paragraph .= $value[0];
      }
    }
    $paragraph .= $end_tag;
    $result .= $paragraph;
  }
  return $result;

}
```

The replace thing is not the only problem..

**When i put in something like**

```
<h1>Hello, dudes</h1>
<p>This stackoverflow test text. Using all special chars like üöä and some 
spicy ß or ? and !. What do u think about some () or % worth about 5000$ or 
€? Iam not sure, but that should be enough. And a link to <a href="google.com">google</a> would be awesome. Whats about further text? Thats buggy, 
isnt it? üöä ?ßß</p>
```

**I get**

```
<h1><span>Hello</span><span>,</span> <span>dudes</span></h1><p>This 
stackoverflow test text. Using all special chars like üöä and some spicy ß 
or ? and !. What do u think about some () or % worth about 5000$ or €? Iam 
not sure, but that should be enough. And a link to <a 
href="http://google.com">google</a> <span>would</span> <span>be</span> 
<span>awesome</span><span>.</span> <span>Whats</span> <span>about</span> 
<span>further</span> <span>text</span><span>?</span> <span>Thats</span> 
<span>buggy</span><span>,</span> <span>isnt</span> <span>it</span><span>?
</span> <span>�</span><span>�</span><span>�</span><span>�</span>
<span>�</span><span>�</span> <span>?</span><span>ßß</span></p>
```

After the `<a>` that is what i need, except the weird special chars. Could somebody please fix that for me? I dont get the point. Honestly i think that i just need the right regex to wrap every word with a `<span>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use this  code:

Try this regex:

```
var str = "This string... it's, an. example! <em>string</em>?!";
str.replace(/([A-z0-9'<>/]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
```

**Example:**

```js
var str = "This string... it's, an. example! <em>string</em>?!";
str = str.replace(/([A-z0-9'<>/]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: This is not a good pattern, read https://stackoverflow.com/a/1658859/2943403